# Best way to pass a struct within a struct to a GSourceFunc

Tags: c, gtk, gobject, clutter

Which way is best to get S to a GSourceFunc?  Or neither?

```
typedef struct{
//...
}S;

struct MS{
//..
S *St;
};

static gboolean AL_Calback(gpointer data){
    S *St = (S*)user_data;
    St->Something = SomethingElse;
    return TRUE;
} 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    //...
    MS *MainStruct = gnew0(MS, 1);
    Mainstruct->St = gnew0(S, 1);
    clutter_threads_add_timeout_full(G_PRIORITY_HIGH, 100, AL_Callback, MainStruct->St, NULL); 
    //...
    }
```

or like this,

```
typedef struct{
//...
}S;

struct MS{
//..
S St;
};

static gboolean AL_Calback(gpointer data){
    MS *MV = (MS*)user_data;
    MV->S.something = SomethingElse;    
    return TRUE;
} 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    //...
    MS *MainStruct = gnew0(MS, 1);
    clutter_threads_add_timeout_full(G_PRIORITY_HIGH, 100, AL_Callback, MainStruct, NULL); 
    //...
    }
```

I've tried other ways, but have not been able to make them work.  clutter_add_timeout needs to take a pointer as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing the parameter to `clutter_threads_add_timeout_Full` via pointer, then you could just pass the address of the `St` member of `MainStruct` thus reducing the need for dynamic allocation (for the inner structure).

```
struct MainStruct{
  //..
  S St; // note: no pointer
};

// in main
MainStruct* ms = gnew0(MS, 1);
clutter_threads_add_timeout_Full(G_PRIORITY_HIGH, 100, AL_Callback, &(ms->St),
    NULL);
```

**Edit**: updated code to dynamically allocate `MainStruct` structure to avoid possible segfault as pointed out by ptomato

Comment: `clutter_threads_add_timeout` won't seam to let me pass anything but a gpointer, which is really just `(void*)`.

Comment: @MVTCplusplus - then just ignore the sentence after the code.  There is no difference between a) having a pointer member and passing that; and b) having a struct member and passing its address (except for memory allocation differences)

Comment: Thanks.  I still haven't done any tests, but I think you pretty much answered my question.

Comment: @Attila, your code runs the risk of the callback running after `ms` goes out of scope, thereby causing a segfault.